# After removing a sheet from an excel workbook with Apache Poi, a sheet remains?

Tags: java, apache, excel, apache-poi

I'm using workbook.removeSheetAt() to remove a certain named sheet from a workbook. However, the workbook contains a new sheet called "Sheet3" after writing it out to disk. What gives? I'm not creating this new sheet anywhere in my code. Note: I am using XSSFWorkbook and all the other XSSF stuff.

Some more info: Here is a snippet from workbook.xml inside the output xlsx. I am deleting sheet with index=2, ostensibly sheetId=3. The template workbook I am starting with only has four sheets.

```
<sheets>
    <sheet r:id="rId1" sheetId="1" name="Sheet1"/>
    <sheet r:id="rId2" sheetId="2" name="Params" state="hidden"/>
    <sheet r:id="rId4" sheetId="4" name="Warnings" state="hidden"/>
    <sheet r:id="rId3" sheetId="5" name="Sheet3"/>
</sheets>
```

Comment: Remember you cannot have a workbook without sheets...

Answer (score 2):

Apache POI is using index based sheets (kinda like an array). If you have a sheet at a position that is greater than x, there must exist a sheet at position x even if it is blank. You could try moving the sheets where n > x to position n - 1 using [setSheetOrder](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#setSheetOrder%28java.lang.String,%20int%29)

Seems like there is a bug report similar to this: [Bug Report](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=47090)

What about hiding the sheet: [setSheetHidden](http://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/Workbook.html#setSheetHidden%28int,%20boolean%29)

Comment: This is useful, but the problem persists even when the sheet I am removing is the last sheet in the workbook. Sheet3 seems to come out of thin air, and it is always at the last position.